# InvalidRegistration of Android Devices at PushWoosh

Tags: php, android, pushwoosh

I am using the following PHP code to send push notifications to the PushWoosh remote API. Its works perfectly for iOS devices and seems to work perfectly for Android (ie I get all the appropriate success responses from the API) but something is amiss with the device registration for Android only as I get InvalidRegistration reports in the PushWoosh console and my Android devices are de-registered from PushWoosh. Anyone shed any light on why? PushWoosh support is virtually none existent (consider this before paying for the service).

The responses messages I am logging are as expected - I get back unknown devices, I register them and receive success response for each registration and I resend the notification and the response message I get back is successful and shows no unknown devices. I then check the push history in the PushWoosh console and the report shows the InvalidRegistration message and devices are removed.

```
<?php
//creates the notifications setting send time etc - this is not where the problem is
$notifications = $this->create_pushwoosh_notifications($devices);
$data = array("application"=>$appcode,
               "auth"=>$apptoken,
               "notifications"=>$notifications);

$pw = new push_woosh();
$r = $pw->create_message($data);
if($r){                         
 $response = json_decode($r[1]); 
 if($response->status_code != 200){
 //there was an error   
 }
error_log($response->status_message);
//retrieve message id's
$messages = $response->response->Messages;
//get any uknown devices associated with the message id's
$unknowns = $response->response->UnknownDevices;
//go through the messages
foreach($response->response->Messages as $message_id){
    //act if there is unknowns
    if(count($unknowns->$message_id)>0){//if there are unknown devices for a message
        //flag that we need to resend once we have finished registering unknown devices
        $resend = true;
           //change the devices in notifications to the unknowns for the message_id that contained unknown devices
            $notifications[$key[0]]['devices']=$unknowns->$message_id;
        //loop unknowns
        foreach($notifications[$key[0]]['devices'] as $device_id){
         $regdata = array(
                   "application"=>$this->appcode,
                    "push_token"=>$devices[$device_id]['user_tokenid'],
                    "language"=>"en",  // optional
                    "hwid"=> $devices[$device_id]['device_id'],//devices indexed by HWID
                    "timezone"=> 3600, // offset in seconds
                    "device_type"=>$devices[$device_id]['device_type'] 
                   );
    }
    //register the device
        $r = $pw->register($regdata);
         if($r){
                $response = json_decode($r[1]); 
                if($response->status_code != 200){
                    //there was an error
            }
            error_log($response->status_message);
            }else{
                //also an error
                }
    }else{//remove the notification as all devices were known and dont need to resend
        unset($notifications[$key[0]]);
        }
}
if($resend){//we need to resend
 //update $data with new $notifications
 $data['notifications']=$notifications;
 $r = $pw->create_message($data);
 if($r){
    $response = json_decode($r[1]); 
    if($response->status_code != 200){
        //there was an error
 }
 error_log($response->status_message);
 }else{
    //also an error
    }
 }
}else{
 //there was an error
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK if this is ever useful to another human I will be happy:

We were using the CakePHP static string method to generate device ID's

```
String::uuid();
```

It outputs a string in this format:

```
485fc381-e790-47a3-9794-1337c0a8fe68
```

PushWoosh had no problems with this when registering iOS devices but was silently failing when using this format for Android devices. Stripped the "-" from this and everything fine.

Boo PushWoosh for not erroring or responding to my email.

Comment: Why do you use CakePHP method when registering devices? hwid should come from the device itself. Sorry this confuses me completely.

Comment: we use a custom device identifier to relate devices to user accounts and store in the device memory and generate these server side. A better description would be app install id as it is updated at every registration of an app instance with our service

Comment: Why don't you set a tag per device? That would achieve the same thing and would not mix up with pushwoosh hwid.

Comment: I will look into that. Doesn't resolve the strange issue of the device not registering correctly though. That still fails if I use a hwid in the original format for android devices only